# Why we don't use extensions for files like .bashrc?

Tags: bash, configuration, file-extension

I am aware that it's a configuration file, but sourcing .bashrc is in fact executing it in bash line by line. I also know, that extensions don't do much in Linux, but when you write some bash script, you often name it "*.sh", and .bashrc is the same, the only difference is that it's sourced by default.

Comment: I think this could be a good question if you asked something along the lines of 'what is the purpose of a file extension'

Answer (score 3):

Linux doesn't really care about what extensions we give to the files, it only checks the permissions as to whether you can run it or you have permission to run it.

What Linux really cares about is the #!/path/to/interpreter at the beginning of the file. like `#!/bin/bash`. This means that the bourne again shell is used to interpret the contents of the file.

**Linux doesn't care about extensions, the .sh is there only for your convenience**

- The .bashrc file is a script that is executed whenever a new terminal session is started in interactive mode. This is what happens when you open a new terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, or just open a new terminal tab.
- The .bashrc file itself contains a series of configurations for the terminal session. This includes setting up or enabling: colouring, completion, the shell history, command aliases and more.
- The Bourne again shell is what reads the .bashrc file, so giving it an extension is practically useless and not required

Comment: **Linux doesn't care about extensions, the .sh is there only for your convenience** people name their scripts with .sh so that they can remember that its a shell script. I had already answered your question.

Comment: None of what you wrote really answers my question.

When people write a simple bash script, they often name it "*.sh". So I don't really care that "extension is practically useless" (I know that) or how .bashrc works - I also already know that. All I want to know is:

**are there historical / practical reasons why people tend to name scripts "*.sh", but they ommit it when writing .bashrc.**

Comment: That's a topic for another forum.

Comment: actually, linux doesn't really care about the shebang either, your shell does.